# Counting individual items in MY SQL or MS SQL column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I have data with column name Rule1 with values ..**Correct**, **Incorrect** and **Undefined**

I was able to get the count of them in this particular column using Group BY

```
select Rule1, count(*) from table_name group by Rule1;
```

I have one more column Rule2 with Values **Correct**, **Incorrect** only
When I try a similar select statement as above, I am getting the only count of Correct and Incorrect

I want to get the count of **Undefined** as zero as no Undefined is present in Rule2 column
How to do that

How I can write a query that needs to show the count of fixed values in multiple columns

Comment: Please let us know what answer worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a derived table that enumerates the possible values with `union all`, then bring your table with a `left join`:

```
select x.rule1, count(t.rule1) cnt
from (select 'Correct' rule1 union all select 'Incorrect' union all select 'Undefined') x
left join mytable t on t.rule1 = x.rule1
group by x.rule1
```

This is a cross-database syntax that will work in both MySQL and SQL Server.

In very recent versions of MySQL, you can use the `values(row ...)` syntax:

```
select x.rule1, count(t.rule1) cnt
from (values row('Correct'), row('Incorrect'), row('Undefined')) x(rule1)
left join mytable t on t.rule1 = x.rule1
group by x.rule1
```

In SQL Server, the equivalent query is:

```
select x.rule1, count(t.rule1) cnt
from (values ('Correct'), ('Incorrect'), ('Undefined')) x(rule1)
left join mytable t on t.rule1 = x.rule1
group by x.rule1
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use sum like this:

```
SELECT 
    sum(case when Rule1 = 'Correct' then 1 else 0 end) AS Rule1Correct,
    sum(case when Rule1 = 'Incorrect' then 1 else 0 end) AS Rule1Incorrect,
    sum(case when Rule1 = 'Undefined' then 1 else 0 end) AS Rule1Undefined,
    sum(case when Rule2 = 'Correct' then 1 else 0 end) AS Rule2Correct,
    sum(case when Rule2 = 'Incorrect' then 1 else 0 end) AS Rule2Incorrect  
FROM 
    table_name 
WHERE 
    1
```

It enables multiple counts in one query. I added all the counts, thought the first two was enough for the idea.

Futhermore I have no idea what is better for the serverload, this or using unions.

Comment: So better anwsered, Eric?